# AJAX request using jquery has no return

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code below:

Code:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'JSON',
  url: 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/04180112/json',
  async: true,
  timeout: 10000
}).done((data) => {
  if (data.erro == undefined) {
    alert("came in");

  } else {
    alert("came in");
  }

}).fail(
  (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) => {
    alert("came in");
  });
```

When accessing the link through the browser the site returns json normally, however using this code above, it is not displaying any alerts as if it did not enter either .done or .fail. This code was working normally, however, it stopped working and I do not know what happened.

Here is the import of jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

## The integrity attribute value is wrong

The first should be obvious if you open the developer tools in your browser and read the Console.

You gave an invalid value to the `integrity` attribute.

[image: console]

## jQuery slim doesn't support ajax

The `ajax` method only appears in the full version of jQuery, not the slim version.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.